# Rudin's Definition of the limit of a function confusion

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definition, epsilon-delta

I was reading Baby Rudin, when I came across the definition he provides for the limit of a function, in terms of sequences. Namely, he says that
for function $f : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow q} f(x) = p$$

if and only if for every sequence $x_n$ in $E$, where $x_n \rightarrow q$, $x_n \neq q$, we have $f(x_n) \rightarrow p$.

I don't understand what would motivate the condition that $x_n \neq q$. Any insight as to why we need this condition would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Consider a function $f$ with a removable discontinuity at $q$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't understand what would motivate the condition that $x_n \neq q$. Any insight as to why we need this condition would be appreciated.

Say $f$ has a removable discontinuity at $q$, with $\lim\limits_{x\to q}f(x)=p,$ but $f(q)=r\ne p$.

Then if we allowed sequences $x_n$ with $x_n=q$, we could have $f(x_n)\to r$, not $p$.

Comment: Why is this a justification? If we allow  $x_n=q$ for all $n>n_0$, that only means $f(x_n)\to r$, for some sequences, not all. So we would simply conclude that $\lim_{x\to q} f(x)$ is not defined. Why is that a nuisance?

Answer (score 4):

For the same reason that $\lim_{x\to q}f(x)=p$ means$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0):\color{red}{0<}|x-q|<\delta\implies\bigl|f(x)-p\bigr|<\varepsilon.$$Note that what happens when $x=q$ is irrelevant (since then $|x-q|\color{red}=0$). So, when we translate this definition into something equivalent using sequences, no term of those sequences can be equal to $q$.

Comment: That just shifts the question to "why is there a $0<$ in the definition?"

Comment: But there *is* a $0<$ in the definition given by Rudin, and therefore he had to put $x_n\ne q$.

Comment: I have no doubt, since also Wikipedia and many other books do that. But I genuinely wonder where it comes from.

Comment: It's actually a matter of taste. Some authors do not have $0<$ in their definition of limit (and I am one of them). But then, if you define$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\Bbb R&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x=0\\0&\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}\end{array}$$then $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$ with respect to the usual definition of limit. But that limit does not exist if we use the definition without the $0<$.

Comment: Right, I agree. It still makes me wonder when and why the >0 became the "usual definition". But I guess that is a question about the history of math.